# Repeat calculation over groups of columns

Tags: r, apply

in the data frame below I want to make average of all the columns and then calculate the fold difference between the first mean for each letter category, like I did it in excel:
[image: Example in Ecxel]

```
A0<-1:4
A1<-2:5
A2<-3:6
A3<-4:7
A4<-5:8
B0<-11:14
B1<-12:15
B2<-13:16
B3<-14:17
B4<-15:18
C0<-21:24
C1<-22:25
C2<-23:26
C3<-24:27
C4<-25:28
```

so far what I could do was:

```
## step 1
df<-data.frame(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4)

## step 2
rbind(df, c(mean(df[,1])/sapply(df[,1:5], mean),
      mean(df[,6])/sapply(df[,6:10], mean), 
      mean(df[,11])/sapply(df[,11:15], mean)))

## step 3
data.frame(t(rbind(df, c(mean(df[,1])/sapply(df[,1:5], mean), 
           mean(df[,6])/sapply(df[,6:10], mean), 
           mean(df[,11])/sapply(df[,11:15], mean)))))

## step 4
ggplot(data.frame(t(rbind(df, c(mean(df[,1])/sapply(df[,1:5], mean), 
       mean(df[,6])/sapply(df[,6:10], mean), 
       mean(df[,11])/sapply(df[,11:15], mean))))),
       aes(1:15, X5)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

After this I can do facets and others, but the step 2 will be very difficult in a big data frame. Do you have any suggestion how I can tell R to do it automatically so I won't have to write it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
# step 1
df <- data.frame(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>% gather(LetterNum, Value) %>% 
       separate(LetterNum, c("Letter", "Num"), sep = 1) %>% 
         group_by(Letter, Num) %>% 
          summarise(Mean1 = mean(Value)) %>% 
            mutate(Mean = first(Mean1)/Mean1)

ggplot(df2, aes(Num, Mean, group = Letter, fill = Letter)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack") + facet_wrap(~Letter)
```

[image]

**OR**

```
# step 1
df <- data.frame(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>% gather(LetterNum, Value) %>% group_by(LetterNum) %>% 
        summarise(Mean1 = mean(Value)) %>% 
          mutate(Group = rep(LETTERS[1:(n()/5)], each = 5)) %>% group_by(Group) %>% 
             mutate(Mean = first(Mean1)/Mean1)


ggplot(df2, aes(LetterNum, Mean, fill = Group)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", 
        position = "stack") + facet_wrap(~Group, scale="free")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question. I try to simulate your data set and create a short scrip utilizing a library called `dplyr`. Here is the script step by step.
1. Create your data set.

```
A0<-1:4
A1<-2:5
A2<-3:6
df <- data.frame(A0,A1, A2, A3)
df
  A0 A1 A2 A3
1  1  2  3  4
2  2  3  4  5
3  3  4  5  6
4  4  5  6  7
```

Now the script that will take the mean of each column.

```
mean.df <- df %>%
rbind(Mean = rowMeans(x = df[],na.rm = TRUE))
mean.df
  A0  A1  A2  A3
1    1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
2    2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
3    3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
4    4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
Mean 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5
```

Now the script that will subtract each mean from the 1st mean. That's what I understood.

```
fold.diff <- mean.df %>%
rbind(Fold_Diff = mean.df[5,] - mean.df[5,1])
fold.diff
       A0  A1  A2  A3
1         1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
2         2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
3         3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
4         4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
Mean      2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5
Fold_Diff 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
```